# Как вывести значение глобальной переменной измененной во вложенной функции?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Проблема следующая, имеется код:

```
var globalVar = "a";

function add() {
    for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {.....
        //Здесь в качестве параметра передается функция aw                                 
        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latlng
        }, aw);
        //Пробую выводит новое значение переменной globalVar, а выводится старое
        alert(globalVar);...
    }
}

function aw(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
            ...
            if (...) {
                globalVar = "qqqq";
                alert(globalVar)
            } else {
                globalVar = "aaaa";
                alert(globalVar)
            }
        }
    }
```

В ф-ции aw переменная меняет, проверено выводом alert. А как потом это измененное значение получить в основной функции, род комментарием: //Пробую выводит новое значение переменной globalVar, а выводится старое

Comment: мне кажется у вас какое то из условий в функции `aw` не срабатывает.. потому что если убрать из вашего кода все условия, то всё работает: http://jsfiddle.net/jPUJT/

Comment: `.geocode()` - асинхронная функция, поэтому колбэк `aw` может вызваться после вызова `alert(globalVar);`

Comment: @Spectre: превратите в ответ? Типичный race, кстати :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить вашу фунцию следующим образом:

```
function aw(results, status) {
    alert('Start AW-function');
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
```

И:

```
  //Пробую выводит новое значение переменной globalVar, а выводится старое
  alert('in main:' + globalVar);
```

Тогда вы увидите, что у вас сначала выдается "in main", а потом уже запускается функция.

Так работает механизм "многопоточности" JS-машины. В общем виде, так и должно быть - вы увидите измененное значение globalVar только тогда, когда/если оно реально изменится...

Колбек - это реакция на событие. То есть если вы написали а = с + 1;, то это будет вычислено, как только "комп" доберется до этой строчки кода. Колбек же будет выполнен только после какого-то события (строго говоря он может не быть вызван никогда).

Если вам нужно что-то по поводу изменения значения делать - добавьте вызов обработчика в колбек... Ну или на таймер повесьте в конце-концов...